# Why doesn't stdin from a file work in case of scp?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to input a password to `scp` automatically from a file called `passwd` with a command

```
scp folder/ user@server.com:./ < passwd
```

but it's not working.

I know we can use password-less SSH as an alternative but I am seeking explanation for why this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question. Very little information has been provided so it will be hard to answer, for more information on how to ask good questions please see [ask]

Comment: [This Q&A on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12236894/2037712) deals with `ssh`, but it should be the very same issue with `scp`.

Comment: "scp and rsync are designed to detect that their password input isn't comming from a terminal to stop just this sort of thing."

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/178732-how-pass-password-input-parameter-scp.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that `scp` uses the `getpass` function to read the password.  From the [glibc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/getpass.html#getpass):

> It tries to connect to the real terminal, `/dev/tty`, if possible, to encourage users not to put plaintext passwords in files; otherwise, it uses `stdin` and `stderr`.